# Prolog: How can I show just names that accompany certain numbers. I have a list in the prolog and I need to show just a few certain names

Tags: prolog

I need to show just 2, 8 and 10, and to show it all in `listName`. I need to show the ID and Name.

This is what I tried:

```
listName(NA):-
    name(ID, NA),
    specific(ID, 2, 8, 10),
    format('xxx', [ID, NA]).
```

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

Using [`memberchk/2`](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=memberchk/2) to implement `specific/4`, quite naturally:

```
listName(NA):-
    name(ID, NA),
    (memberchk(ID,[2,8,10]) 
     -> format("ID = ~q, NA = ~q\n", [ID, NA]) 
     ;  (format("Nope\n"),fail)).
```